# How to remove gap from 2 resizable input elements?

Tags: html, css

**For quick assessment, run Code Snippet in Full page, then adjust browser screen. There will be a larger gap between the number, and the input range as the browser gets smaller

I have 2 input elements on top of one another. Essentially, an `input` range with the `value` number displayed underneath it.

Visually looks appealing, up until I resize my browser window. The input elements become smaller (as intended), although now there is a gap between them that gets bigger the smaller the elements get. How do I go about eliminating the gap?

HTML (inside a table)

```css
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    position: absolute;
    width: 40%;
    height: calc(50vh);
    left: 30%;
}
td {
    width: 50%;
    height: calc(2.5vh);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
input[type="text"] {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    color: black;
    font: calc(2.5vh) Risque;
    outline: none;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 50%;
    height: calc(1.5vh);
    border-radius: calc(0.5vh);
    background: #d3d3d3;
    outline: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
}
.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: calc(2.5vh);
    height: calc(2.5vh);
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #4CAF50;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: calc(2.5vh);
    height: calc(2.5vh);
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #4CAF50;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" class="slider" id="settings-sfx-range"><br>
            <input type="text" id="settings-sfx-range-num" value="100">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I've tried putting the elements in a `<div>` instead of `<table>`, same thing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align`

```
input[type="text"]{
   vertical-align:top;
}
.slider {
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

```css
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    position: absolute;
    width: 40%;
    height: calc(50vh);
    left: 30%;
}
td {
    width: 50%;
    height: calc(2.5vh);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
input[type="text"] {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    color: black;
    font: calc(2.5vh) Risque;
    outline: none;
    pointer-events: none;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 50%;
    height: calc(1.5vh);
    border-radius: calc(0.5vh);
    background: #d3d3d3;
    outline: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: calc(2.5vh);
    height: calc(2.5vh);
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #4CAF50;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: calc(2.5vh);
    height: calc(2.5vh);
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #4CAF50;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" class="slider" id="settings-sfx-range"><br>
            <input type="text" id="settings-sfx-range-num" value="100">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```